# Finding scoped packages on npm's api

Tags: npm

I am doing a research project, and I am trying to get package data from npm's api. I am using the registry.npmjs.org/'package name' api. I am not sure if scoped packages are on this api. I know this will be deprecated soon as npm is changing a lot, but does anyone know how I can get package information on a scoped package?
 The information I definitely need is dependencies, maintainers, repo links if any. An example of a scoped package name I would have is @types/node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2Fnode

You just need to replace `/` with `%2F`

Comment: wow I tried encoding both the @ and the / but not just the slash! you are amazing thanks for the ridiculously easy answer